# How do I parse this php array in python?

Tags: python, parsing

A webform application asked to export a form I've made gives me a `.txt` file with the following content, corresponding to a `php` array:

```
$webform = array (
  'nid' => '316018',
  'next_serial' => '301',
  'confirmation' => '',
  'confirmation_format' => 'wysiwyg_user',
```

...

```
  ),
  'components' =>
  array (
    45 =>
    array (
      'nid' => 316018,
      'cid' => '45',
      'pid' => '0',
      'form_key' => 'new_1601200968601',
```

...

How can I parse this in python?

Comment: This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: You should probably `json_encode` it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `php-cli`,

```
echo "json_encode($webform);" >> file.txt
php -a < file.txt > file.json
```

and then

```
import json
with open('file.json') as json_data: 
  data = json.load(json_data) 
data.keys()
```

Thanks to @OneCricketeer.